# How to change size of thumbnails in WordPress with Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am simply trying to use a medium thumbnail size for the `background-image` in my advanced custom fields gallery. I am fairly new to wordpress and understand conceptually what I need to do, however I'm having trouble finding the right syntax to implement 'add_image_size' function that's been created to my loop and image.

This seems like it should work, however adding the 'medium' and 'size' attributes is prohibiting the image from appearing. ( please not when I cut out `$image_thumbnail` that the pictures appear as they should )

```
           <div class="container gallery-section">
                <?php foreach(get_field('gallery_image') as $gallery_image) { ?>
                <?php
                 $image = $gallery_image['gallery_picture'];
                 $image_thumbnail = $image['gallery_picture']['sizes']['medium'];
                ?>
                <div class="gallery-image">

                    <a href="<?php echo $image; ?>" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image_thumbnail; ?>');" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"></a>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Here is my functions.php

```
if (function_exists('add_theme_support'))
{
    // Add Menu Support
    add_theme_support('menus');

    // Add Thumbnail Theme Support
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('large', 700, '', true); // Large Thumbnail
    add_image_size('medium', 250, '', true); // Medium Thumbnail
    add_image_size('small', 120, '', true); // Small Thumbnail
    add_image_size('custom-size', 700, 200, true); // Custom Thumbnail Size call using the_post_thumbnail('custom-size');

}
```

*****EDIT*****

```
<div class="container gallery-section">
    <?php 
    $gallery_field = get_field('gallery_image'); // the field name that you set for the gallery field
    foreach($gallery_field as $gallery_image) {
    $image = $gallery_image['gallery_picture']; // url for the image that you upload same sizes..
    $image_thumbnail = $image['sizes']['medium']; // url for the medium size
                        ?>
    <div class="gallery-image">
    <a href="<?php echo $image; ?>" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image_thumbnail; ?>');" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"></a>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the image url to oject url and used this code.

```
<?php while(have_rows('gallery_image')) { the_row(); ?>
<?php $image = get_sub_field('gallery_picture'); ?>
<div class="gallery-image">
    <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image['sizes']['medium']; ?>');" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"></a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with this loop and getting the results from the array.

its should be something like this:

```
<div class="container gallery-section">
    <?php 
    $gallery_field = get_field('gallery_image'); // the field name that you set for the gallery field
    //print_r($gallery_field); you can see the array structure.
    foreach($gallery_field as $gallery_image) {
        $image = $gallery_image['url']; // url for the image that you upload same sizes..
        $image_thumbnail = $gallery_image['sizes']['medium']; // url for the medium size
        ?>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <a href="<?php echo $image; ?>" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image_thumbnail; ?>');" class="fancybox" rel="gallery"></a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

One more thing you can set the sizes `medium` and `large` from the Settings->media if you want.

I'll break it into pieces so you could understand.

In the ACF admin you create a new gallery field, and you called him **gallery_image**.
Now to get this field in the template you use:

```
$gallery_field = get_field('gallery_image');
```

This field return you an array of all the images that you upload to this field in some page, post.

The array look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 199
            [alt] => 
            [title] => _YON7864
            [caption] => 
            [description] => 
            [mime_type] => image/jpeg
            [url] => http://localhost/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/YON7864.jpg
            [width] => 1772
            [height] => 1177
            [sizes] => Array
                (
                    [thumbnail] => http://localhost/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/YON7864-150x150.jpg
                    [thumbnail-width] => 150
                    [thumbnail-height] => 150
                    [medium] => http://localhost/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/YON7864-250x166.jpg
                    [medium-width] => 250
                    [medium-height] => 166
                    [large] => http://localhost/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/YON7864-700x464.jpg
                    [large-width] => 700
                    [large-height] => 464
                    [small] => http://localhost/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/YON7864-120x79.jpg
                    [small-width] => 120
                    [small-height] => 79
                    [custom-size] => http://localhost/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/YON7864-700x200.jpg
                    [custom-size-width] => 700
                    [custom-size-height] => 200
                )

        )
)
```

Now to get all the images you run a loop on the array.

```
foreach($gallery_field as $gallery_image) {
    //inside the loop
}
```

`$image_gallery` is now array for single image and its run in the loop.

And inside the loop you get the url and some url of image size that you want.

To get the url of the image that you upload in real size you need to use the key `['url']` as you see in the array.

To get the url for other image sizes you need to get inside the array key `['sizes']` and then you choose a size like `['medium']` or `['large']`

Its should look like this.

```
foreach($gallery_field as $gallery_image) {
    // $gallery_image is our array for each image
    $image = $gallery_image['url']; // to get the url we need to use ['url']
    $image_thumbnail = $gallery_image['sizes']['medium']; // to get the medium size image url we need to use ['sizes']['medium']
}
```

Comment: see my edits. It's not getting the url to the background-image. the url is rendering as 'h'. @Shibi

Comment: I edit my answer so you can understand... this 2 lines is ruin you all `$image = $gallery_image['gallery_picture'];` and `$image_thumbnail = $image['sizes']['medium'];`

Comment: I understand how it works and the structure. As I said before, that doesn't retrieve anything. What I have in my newest edits it closer. The effort is much appreciated tho.

Comment: This `$image = $gallery_image['gallery_picture'];` should be `$image = $gallery_image['url'];`  and this `$image_thumbnail = $image['sizes']['medium'];` should be `$image_thumbnail = $gallery_image['sizes']['medium'];`

Comment: you can check if the field return you the array by adding `print_r($gallery_field);` after `$gallery_field = get_field('gallery_image');` if its return you the array so just update what i wrote in my last comment, or just replace your code with my first code in the answer.

Comment: I answered my own question. I took a different approach and figured it out.Thanks anyway.